# Multiply a constant to each array element

Tags: postgresql

I have a column of TYPE `integer[]` in PostgreSQL. I want to multiply 1000 to each row and each element of the column in that table. Each row has varying length of arrays.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
UPDATE tab
SET  col = array(select 1000 * unnest(col));
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=39d107f92440b6d9da948f73b2c80962)**